# Jquery anchor hover fade | Cross browser issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

See here for code: http://jsfiddle.net/ecFBK/10/

I'm having a hard time getting this to work in IE 7 and IE 8

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/ecFBK/13/

I changed the span(hover class) to a div, I tested on a IE 8 on VM

If you need to use spans then attach it with append()

http://jsfiddle.net/ecFBK/14/

Comment: Very close - go it working in IE 7 - just not IE 8 and google chrome... have no clue why!?!